# JqueryUI DatePicker

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a form field which is using datepicker.

The form field is has a value applied via php in the format `yymmdd`

```
<input type='text' id='date' name='date' value='<?php echo $date ?>'>
```

JQuery:

```
$("body").on('focus', '#date', function(){
        $( this ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "d MM yy", minDate: 0, maxDate: "+1Y -1D"});     
    });
```

When the page loads the value appears in the field eg: `160914`

What I'd like to do is have datepicker detect this format correctly, so when the picker appears the 14th September 2016 is highlighted.

I'd also like when the user selects a date, the field would show eg: 21 September 2016, but the value available to be written back to the database would be `160921`

Can this be done  ?  Can someone point me in the right direction ?

Thanks

Comment: Look into altField and altFormat for sending a different format than the one displayed.

Comment: Thanks - is there anything that can be done about how it is displayed and having the picker finding it ?

Comment: What stops you to change `'<?php echo $date ?>'` to properly format the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i found solution for you. Just to note that your dateFormat was wrong. Check [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-gotoCurrent) for all details. However :) Maybe is good idea to print better date with Php, some useful format like Y-m-d. Check that and good luck:

```js
$('input').datepicker({ altFormat: "y mm d", dateFormat: "dd MM yy", minDate: 0, maxDate: "+1Y -1D"});
$('input').val($.datepicker.formatDate("dd MM yy", $('input').datepicker("getDate")));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input type='text' id='date' name='date' value='16 09 14'>
```

Comment: Thanks this helps a lot :)